# Zero net external force

Tags: kinematics

Is it possible to have a changing kinetic energy when the resultant of the external forces on the system of particles is zero?

According to my thoughts, if the net external forces are zero, the body will not experience any acceleration, and thus no change in velocity, and therefore the kinetic energy should remain constant. The same concept will apply to linear momentum.

Is this right?

Comment: Kinetic energy is observer dependent. You can change the  inertial frame from which you are observing and the kinetic energy of an object will change. That's not a physical change, of course. If you are only looking at the scenario with a real physical change, then something has to perform work on that object, which implies both a net force and a displacement.

Comment: Or a net torque and change in angular momentum.

Comment: @Gert Well... problem is that only linear momentum will stay conserved. Angular momentum can change depending on the inertial frame. Don't understand why though.

Comment: @CuriousOne So depending on our selection of the inertial frame, we will observe different kinetic energies? How though?

Comment: @Gummybears: sit on a moving train. Everything that appears stationary to you has no kinetic energy to you. For anyone observing the train from an outside perspective the train and everything in it has kinetic energy.

Comment: The difference in kinetic energy from different observers is given by the fact that a wall that is stationary and thus harmless from my point of view can seriously hurt you if you are running into it.

Comment: @Gummybears: "problem is that only linear momentum will stay conserved". Angular momentum is conserved too, play with a spinning top or gyroscope.

Comment: @Gert What I'm unable to understand, then, is why the same concept does not apply to linear momentum. And according to the answer given, the angular momentum is not conserved when observing from different inertial frames.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's a nice way to explain it. However, why doesn't it apply to linear momentum as well?

Comment: The numerical value of all of these quantities depends on the observer. If you go into a different system, linear momentum can also change. It just doesn't change under a simple constant translation. Angular momentum doesn't change under a constant rotation. Kinetic energy doesn't change under either. If you want to understand the deeper mathematical connection, then you need to learn about Noether's theorem which links symmetries to conserved values.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something simple in the wording of the question, but let us consider two charges of the opposite sign that initially had zero velocity; there are no external forces. I guess such two charges qualify as a "system of particles". The charges attract each other, and their total kinetic energy will start to increase at the expense of their potential energy.

If you think that the two charges are a "system" but not a "body", consider an oscillating spring or a vibrating string.

Answer (score 0):

What is said in the above comments is true. The kinetic energy stays the same because the absence of a net force implies that the only non-vanishing contribution to the energy of the body is kinetic energy. Since the total energy is conserved, the result follows.